# Python: How do I write an array grabbed via Selenium class onto a txt file?

Tags: python, selenium

The links.txt file contains 3 links that I'm looping thru. I am trying to write the array onto a separate output.txt file. However, the output ignores the contents first 2 links.

If there is a way to do this without json, I'm open to it.

Current Output in output.txt:

```
["Addee", "Brian]
```

Desired Output in output.txt:

```
["Shenmue", "Addison"]
["Mike", "Todd"]
["Addee", "Brian"]
```

Current Code:

```
one = open("links.txt", "r")

for two in one.readlines():
  driver.get(two)
  sleep(3)
  
  arr1=[element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('update_models')]
  
  with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(arr1, outfile)
```

My Attempt at a solution:

```
one = open("links.txt", "r")

for two in one.readlines():
  driver.get(two)
  sleep(3)
  
  arr1=[element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('update_models')]
  
  with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(arr1 + "\n", outfile)
```

Output for attempt:

```
  json.dump(arr1 + "\n", outfile)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

**EDIT:**
When I printed the array according to the following code:

```
one = open("links.txt", "r")

for two in one.readlines():
  driver.get(two)
  sleep(3)
  
  arr1=[element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('update_models')]

  print(arr1)
```

I got this output:

```
["Shenmue", "Addison"]
["Mike", "Todd"]
["Addee", "Brian"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, `w` write the file afresh each time. So, even though I see your `json.dump` inside the for loop, I think it is over-writing the text for each loop, and that is why you see only the last element list. Try `a` instead of `w` which appends instead of writes.
This should work. It should append instead of write afresh for each loop.

```
   with open("output.txt", "a") as outfile:
        json.dump(arr1, outfile)
```

Comment: Thank you. You may just add `f.write("\n")` as the last line for each iteration of the loop to get to the next line